# Plotly-dash can user edit and save changes to dashboard?

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I'm looking at using plotly-dash however it is still not clear to me whether what I want to do is possible.

I would like to build a UI that allows the user the upload their data, set some parameters and do some data analysis. Once this is done the user would be able to save the dashboard they've created to file, so they can reopen it as it is and make further changes if required.
So once this is done the user can either open the blank UI and start another dashboard or open the dashboard they created previously.

Does plotly-dash have this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, yes that is possible with Dash. How easy or difficult it will be depends largely on what sort of analysis you want users to be able to do, and less so on saving/loading the dashboard.

Comment: Thank you, the analysis to do would be pretty basic I think, setting thresholds lines on graphs and seeing if a curve crosses the threshold and then showing a summary of the samples that were positive based on this for example.
Could you point me to any resources on how to save and load the dashboard please?

Comment: I don't have any resources besides my own experience doing similar projects. It should mostly be a matter of saving configuration settings. If you use a slider, for example, to set the threshold, then you could include that slider's value in a callback with other settings to store in a JSON object which you then write to a DB or a file or something.